# Why my published var is not being updated by my view?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ios14

I am making a personal project to study SwiftUI. All was going well, the I noticed a bug on my app.

I have the simple view bellow, that saves a description, a value and some tags on my ViewModel. I am having an issue with the **$viewModel.value**. That variable is not being filled with values from the view.

I supose that my **@Published var value: Double?** from my ViewModel should be updated whenever the user types some value. Thing is, it is not updating on any iPhone 11 and up, but it works perfectly on the iPhone 8.

```
public struct AddBillView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: AddBillViewModel
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    
    public let onExpenseCreated: ((_ expense: Expense)->Void)
    
    public var body: some View {
        Text("Add Expense")
        VStack {
            TextField("Descrição", text: $viewModel.name)
            HStack {
                Text("Valor \(NumberFormatter.currency.currencySymbol)")
                CurrencyTextField("Value", value: $viewModel.value)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.leading)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Tags")
                TextField("car pets home",
                          text: $viewModel.tags)
            }
                
            Picker("Type", selection: $viewModel.type) {
                Text("Paid").tag("Paid")
                Text("Unpaid").tag("Unpaid")
                Text("Credit").tag("Credit")
            }
        }.navigationTitle("+ Expense")
        
        Button("Adicionar") {
            if !viewModel.hasExpense() {
                return
            }
            onExpenseCreated(viewModel.expense())
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    public init(viewModel outViewModel: AddBillViewModel,
                onExpenseCreated: @escaping ((_ expense: Expense)->Void)) {
        self.viewModel = outViewModel
        self.onExpenseCreated = onExpenseCreated
    }
}
```

And I have a ViewModel:

```
public class AddBillViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var type: String = "Paid"
    @Published var tags: String = ""
    @Published var value: Double?
    
    
    init(expense: Expense?=nil) {
        self.name = expense?.name ?? ""
        self.type = expense?.type.rawValue ?? "Paid"
        self.tags = expense?.tags?.map { String($0.name) }.joined(separator: " ") ?? ""
        self.value = expense?.value
    }
    
    func hasExpense() -> Bool {
        if self.name.isEmpty ||
            self.value == nil ||
            self.value?.isZero == true {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func expense() -> Expense {
        let tags = self.tags.split(separator: " ").map { Tag(name: String($0)) }
        return Expense(name: self.name, value: self.value ?? 0.0 ,
                       type: ExpenseType(rawValue: self.type)!,
                       id: UUID().uuidString,
                       tags: tags)
    }
}
```

Then I use my view:

```
                AddBillView(viewModel: AddBillViewModel()) { expense in
                    viewModel.add(expense: expense)
                    viewModel.state = .idle
                }
```

I already google it and spend a couple of hours looking for an answer, with no luck. Someone have any ideas?

**Edited**

Here is the code for the CurrencyTextField. I`m using this component:
https://github.com/youjinp/SwiftUIKit/blob/master/Sources/SwiftUIKit/views/CurrencyTextField.swift

But the component works perfectly fine on iPhone 8 simulator and with a @State property inside my view. It does not work only with my ViewModel

Comment: Is it limited to that one field? In other words, does the name field work, but the value one doesn't? My suspicion is that you'll need to show the code for `CurrencyTextField`

Comment: As jnpdx said, you will need to define CurrencyTextField for us

Comment: Try either an EnvironmentObject or Binding. How is AddBillView being used? The lifecycle of addBillViewModel depends a lot on how it is instantiated.

Comment: I added the source code for CurrencyTextField

Comment: @Helperbug I updated the question with the viewModel constructor. I`m only instantiating the ViewModel with  an empty constructor

Comment: @ikkarion create a property for AddBillViewModel in the class that own AddBillView - and - change StateObject to EnvironmentObject. My guess is that nothing in the domain is hanging on to the reference when the View's object (StateObject) is instantiated in the call-tree. Give that ViewModel a home!

Comment: After watching this video I started passing unbound data down the call stack [SwiftUI Best Practice Review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4hxE7VQvTA). Just something else to consider. Instead of having @State in views, have lets, and keep the property wrappers toward the top of the call tree.

Comment: @Helperbug I did the EnrionmentObject, but the problem continues... I think this maybe is linked with some issue during build time for the iPhone 11 and above. My viewModel is not used in any other place, so there is no cross line..

Comment: Even using EnvironmentObject it matters how it is instantiated. There needs to be a property on a class to hold on to the reference.

Comment: @Helperbug

I figured it out! The problem was that my AddBillViewModel is an ObservableObject and I was marking each property with Published. This was causing some kind of double observable object.

I removed the Published and it started working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem was that my **AddBillViewModel** is an **ObservableObject** and I was marking each property with **@Published**. This was causing some kind of double observable object.

**I removed the @Published** and it started working again.